# IIS Express recycles app pool after edit of css, js, or another "no bin" file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

Dev platform : VS 2013, MVC 5, IIS Express 7.5.

The problem : When I edit a javascript on the fly and hit F5 to refresh screen IIS Express recycles the app pool for no apparent reason. And because I am loading some assemblies during app start this causes an error :

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\34d1a25b\a6535eb1\Module1.dll' because it is being used by another process.

which is logical. But why IIS Express recycles the app pool?

I have tried to track down the reason according [Scott Gu post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/433194) but the error is the viewer is yet again a nonsense :

> The description for Event ID 0 from source .NET Runtime cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event: 
>   _shutDownMessage=Change in App_Offline.htm HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown Change in App_Offline.htm HostingEnvironment caused
>   shutdown Change in App_Offline.htm
>
> _shutDownStack=   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)    at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()   ... 
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
>   string/message table

The only thing that speaks to me is

> _shutDownMessage=Change in App_Offline.htm HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown Change in App_Offline.htm

There are similar questions here on stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944172/how-to-troubleshoot-app-domain-shutdown-due-to-change-in-app-offline-htm-afte) and [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965346/app-offline-htm-created-deleted-whenever-i-check-out-a-file-in-tfs) and a probable answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2148380/1042934) but I still do not get it - who is responsible for this and what is the main reason? Or there are different reasons for the different cases?

Comment: In which directory stored js file?

Comment: in MyMvc5Proj/Scripts/myJsModules/MyJsModule

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16933217/1042934) and it is more like a workaround with the desired side effect rather then full solution with proper explanation.

1. Browse to %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0
2. Delete app_offline.htm
3. Create a FOLDER with the same name - app_offline.htm
4. Done

I did this and the problem disappeared.